# SQL - Is there any way to simple count it?

Tags: mysql, sql

From two days i'm trying to solve some problem - without success.
This is my table user_actions:

```
userId | actionId
------------------
12     | 0004243
12     | 0004243
12     | 1346454
542    | 4356675
235    | 1346454
235    | 0004243
235    | 1346454
235    | 1346454
```

and I need to count, how many users performed an action (actionId).
Regarding to the example above the output should looks like:

```
actionId | howManyUsers
-----------------------
0004243  | 2
1346454  | 2
4356675  | 1
```

Could someone clever help me and explain to me the method?
Thank You.

Comment: Please see "related" sidebar. There are many examples.

Comment: You worked on this for ***two days*** and then turned for help? Could you provide ***just one*** example of what you tried, and explain what you could have tried for ***two days***?

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
SELECT actionId, COUNT(DISTINCT userId) AS howManyUsers
FROM user_actions
GROUP BY actionId
```

Is this helpful?

Answer (score 3):

The correct query uses `count(distinct)`:

```
select actionID, count(distinct userId) as howManyUsers  
from table
group by actionID
```

Answer (score 0):

The query is simple.

Select Count(*) as howmanyusers, actionID from TableX groupby actionId

Answer (score 0):

try following query

```
SELECT actionId, COUNT(userId) AS howManyUsers 
FROM user_actions
GROUP BY actionId
```

Answer (score 0):

I simulated it, actually this query gives me the correct output:

```
SELECT actionId, COUNT(DISTINCT actionId) AS howManyUsers
FROM user_actions
GROUP BY userId
```

Comment: Okay, seems sqlfiddle.com was not right. But they both work in phpmyadmin.

Comment: The question says *"count users"*. You count actions.

Comment: You're right, i just reversed it because I got strange output when using the above (correct) queries. Don't know why, but mine gave me the only correct output first. Maybe I was doing something wrong. In phpmyadmin they work fine, so please ignore my post. ;)